# Unexplained Inconsistency when Downloading an XLS file with Ruby Mechanize after redirect

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I have a script that visits fcc.gov, then clicks a link which triggers a download:

```
require "mechanize"

docket_number = "12-268" #"96-128"

url = "http://apps.fcc.gov/ecfs/comment_search/execute?proceeding=#{docket_number}"
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::DirectorySaver.save_to 'downloads'

agent.get(url) do |page|
    link = page.link_with(:text => "Export to Excel file")
    xls = agent.click(link)
end
```

This works fine when `docket_number` is "12-268". But when you change it to "96-128", Mechanize downloads the html of the page instead of the desired spreadsheet.

The urls for both pages are:

- http://apps.fcc.gov/ecfs/comment_search/execute?proceeding=12-268 (works)
- http://apps.fcc.gov/ecfs/comment_search/execute?proceeding=96-128 (this is where I need help)

As you can see, if you visit each page in a browser (I'm using Chrome) and click "Export to Excel file", a spreadsheet file is downloaded and there is not problem. "96-128" has many more rows, so when you click on the Export link, it takes you to a new page that refreshes every 10 seconds or so until the file begins downloading. How can I get around this and why is there this inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking Export on 96-128 takes you to a page that refreshes using this kind of a tag (I've never heard of it before):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=/ecfs/comment_search/export?exportType=xls"/>
```

By default, Mechanize will not follow these refreshes. To get around that, change a setting on `agent`:

```
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166480/94154

Answer (score 0):

The proceeding 12-268 has 48 entries, 96-128 has 4046.
When I click at 'Export to Excel File' on the latter, there sometimes is a page saying:

> Finished processing 933 of 4046 records.
>   Click if this page does not reload automatically.

I guess mechanize is seeing this, too.

Comment: Hey, @Huluk. I just solved this on my own, see my answer below.